# Migration laravel 5.5 : cannot create table except users table and password_reset table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

i have 9 tables, when i run command :

> php artisan migrate

only users table, migration table and password_reset table are created in my database. this is my sample code

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateAlatsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('alats', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('merk_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('kategori_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('operator_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('nama');
            $table->string('no_plat',15);
            $table->date('tahun');
            $table->string('volume',20);
            $table->text('keterangan');
            $table->enum('status',['ada','disewa','servis']);
            // $table->timestamp('created_at');
            // $table->timestamp('updated_at');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('merk_id')->references('id')->on('merks')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('kategori_id')->references('id')->on('kategoris')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('operator_id')->references('id')->on('operators')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('alats');
    }
}`

please help me..?

Comment: any error from terminal??? or provide migration code sample.

Comment: this message on terminal   :  
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `db_sidewiratih`.`#
 sql-53c_8d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQ
 L: alter table `alats` add constraint `alats_merk_id_foreign` foreign key (
 `merk_id`) references `merks` (`id`) on delete CASCADE)



 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `db_sidewiratih`.`#
 sql-53c_8d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Can you please provide sample code of both migrations???

Comment: this is my code for alats table : https://pastebin.com/7zsTci9i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migration files need to be migrated in right order. You can't migrate a table with a non existing foreign key.

You probably have a foreign key in some migration and the id key for that will come to existence later in the next migration file. That is why you get this error.

Check your migration files and watch out on order they get created.

For example if you have a foreign key `alats_merk_id_foreign` then the migration file with `alats_merk_id` must be migrated before.

Answer (score 2):

```
Schema::create('alats', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('merk_id')->unsigned();
});

Schema::table('alats', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->foreign('merk_id')
        ->references('merk_id')->on('merk_id_table_name')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

First create only table and then create foreign key.
And make sure merk_id_table should migrate first.

Comment: He will get the same error with your code! Because it's not the problem with that migration file that he posted in pastebin it is the fact that the id key from which he wants to create a foreign key does not exist yet

Comment: yes I have written it "First create only table and then create foreign key. And make sure merk_id_table should migrate first."  So he will definetly get key

Comment: what about others? he has 3 foreign keys

Comment: He have to do the same for 3 others, I have just put example for only one.

Comment: now table "alats" are created, but other tables not created, i have same error message

Comment: You have to create these table first 'kategoris', 'merks', 'operators' and then try to give foreign key.

Comment: my tables is : users, password_resets, alats, kategoris, transaksis, pembelians, merks, operators, and services. and only users,password_resets, alats are created

Comment: so , can i make all my table with command "php artisan migration" in the same time

Comment: try php artisan migrate:refresh and if you have created merks, kategoris, operators tables after alats, you have to delete it. So first create migrations of these tables merks, kategoris, operators and then create alats table migration. So it will migrate in sequence. I hope after this you will not face any errors.

Answer (score 1):

if you did every thing in all answers

I think your problem is from the foreign/primary key **type and length**

so you may create the id as integer and its corresponding foreign key as an integer with different length, or even as another type as string forexample

so try to make integers with unsigned and same length

try to use `->unsigned()->length(10)...`

#### solution:

to make the pimary key and its corresponding foreign key in the same exact type and length

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

```
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

        Schema::create('alats', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('merk_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('kategori_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('operator_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('nama');
            $table->string('no_plat',15);
            $table->date('tahun');
            $table->string('volume',20);
            $table->text('keterangan');
            $table->enum('status',['ada','disewa','servis']);
            // $table->timestamp('created_at');
            // $table->timestamp('updated_at');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('merk_id')->references('id')->on('merks')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('kategori_id')->references('id')->on('kategoris')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('operator_id')->references('id')->on('operators')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

You need to replicate the above for every migration.